# C++ Iterator Facade for sockets

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming, iterator, facade

I was wondering if there is a good implementation (library) of a C++ iterator facade around sockets. I've gone through the Boost Iterator library and ASIO, and can't seem to find anything. An open source solution would be great!

I'm looking for a solution to the following use-case:

```
int socket_handler = 0;

socket_iterator it(socket_handler);
socket_iterator end;

//read mode 1:
while (it != end)
{
  char c = *it;
   .
   .
  ++it;
}

//read mode 2:
while (it != end)
{
  std::string s = *it;
   .
   .
  ++it;
}

//write mode 1:
unsigned char c = 0;
while (c < 100)
{
  *it = c++;
  .
  .
  ++it;
}

//write mode 2:
std::sttring s = "abc";
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
  *it = s;
   .
   .
  ++it;
}
```

Note: it == end, when the connection is disconnected.

Comment: Boost.Asio's [socket iostreams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/networking/iostreams.html) didn't work for you?

Comment: @Chris: It doesn't seem to be compatible with istream_iterator and ostream_iterator.

Comment: This sounds a lot like "Leaky Abstraction": http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html

Comment: @Nikolai: According to that article everything in programming above machine language is a leaky abstraction.  Leaky abstractions can still be useful.

Comment: @Michael, true. But this one feels especially leaky :) Networks are oh so special.

Answer (score 2):

@Gerdiner, Boost.Asio is the winner. Regarding your istream_iterator, check out the following:

```
boost::asio::streambuf myBuffer;
std::string myString;

// Convert streambuf to std::string
std::istream(&myBuffer) >> myString;
```

With ASIO, you won't need an iterator, however. See the following async client for a starting place.

[Async HTTP Client](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/client/async_client.cpp)